# After getting active, UISerachBar is misplaced to right side of the screen in the detailView of UISplitviewController on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISplitViewcontroller. In the xib of detailView of spilviewController, I have UISearchBarController as tableheadView. Upon clicking on searchBar the keyboard pops up but the searchbar moves to right of screen and stays at same position after dismissing keybaord. 
I couldnot upload a image so I am attaching a pic from similar question i found on stackOverflow. http://iferiados.com.br/bug.jpg

preferredDisplayMode for UISplitViewcontroller is Automatic. And I don't want to set it to AllVisible

Here is the code

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = RGBA(48, 153, 185, 1);
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.tblClinicians.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: No .. I am not using autoLayout